# Filling random values in two sheets from a single sheet via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random

I fill out random values in two sheets (Testfall-Input_Vorschlag) and (Testfall-Input_Antrag) out of another sheet (ADMIN_ARB11).

I have 371 rows in sheet (Testfall-Input_Vorschlag) and I have 488 rows in sheet (Testfall-Input_Antrag). I have 859 columns in sheet (ADMIN_ARB11).

I pick a random value from each of the 1st 371 columns (from ADMIN_ARB11) and I put them in the 371 rows in sheet (Testfall-Input_Vorschlag) and then I pick a random value from each of the next 488 columns (from ADMIN_ARB11) and put them in 488 rows in sheet (Testfall-Input_Antrag).

```
Sub Random_Befüllung_Vorschlag_ARB11()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, LB As Long, UB As Long
Set sh1 = Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag")
Set sh2 = Sheets("ADMIN_ARB11")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = 7 To 300
        LB = 2
        If sh1.Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Or sh1.Cells(1, j) = "ARB13" Or sh1.Cells(1, j) = "FVB1" Or sh1.Cells(1, j) = "FVB1E" Or sh1.Cells(1, j) = "FVB4" Or sh1.Cells(1, j) = "FVB4E" Then
            sh1.Cells(2, j) = sh1.Cells(1, j) & "_Schicht 1"
            sh1.Cells(3, j) = "TPL maximale Eingaben"
            If j = 7 Then
                sh1.Cells(6, j) = 1
            Else
                sh1.Cells(6, j) = sh1.Cells(6, j - 1) + 1
            End If
            sh1.Cells(5, j) = "TF " & sh1.Cells(6, j)
            sh1.Cells(7, j) = "Test_GE"
            sh1.Cells(8, j) = "x"


            For i = 11 To 382
            UB = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, i - 10).End(xlUp).Row 'i - 10 controls column in Admin start at col 1.

            sh1.Cells(i, j).Value = sh2.Cells(Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB), i - 10)

            Next

        End If



    If sh1.Cells(1, j) = vbNullString Then
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Sub Random_Befüllung_Antrag_ARB11()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, LB As Long, UB As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag")
Set sh1 = Sheets("Testfall-Input_Antrag")
Set sh2 = Sheets("ADMIN_ARB11")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Testfallinfo in Testfall-Input_Antrag kopieren
    For j = 7 To 300
    If Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "ARB13" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB1" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB1E" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB4" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB4E" Then
    Union(ws.Cells(1, j), ws.Cells(2, j), ws.Cells(3, j), ws.Cells(4, j), ws.Cells(5, j), ws.Cells(6, j), ws.Cells(7, j), ws.Cells(8, j)).Copy
    sh1.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If



        LB = 2
        If sh1.Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Then
            For i = 13 To 501
                UB = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 364).End(xlUp).Row 'i - 10 controls column in Admin start at col 1.
                sh1.Cells(i, j).Value = sh2.Cells(Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB), i + 364)


            Next
        End If

    If sh1.Cells(1, j) = vbNullString Then
    Exit For
    End If
    Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works as expected but it takes 5 min to run the code. How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `Objects` such as `Sheets`, `Cells` & `Range` takes considerable time. Try to reduce their use as much as you can by assigning their values to a variable before entering a `For` loop.

```
If Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "ARB13" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB1" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB1E" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB4" Or Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "FVB4E" Then
```

These chained `If` statements will each be getting the value of your test cell in turn, each one accessing `Sheets` and `Cells` individually over and over for the same value, this will likely be having an impact on your performance.

Try putting the cell value in a variable before your tests:

```
testCell = Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j).Value
If testCell = "ARB11" Or testCell = "ARB13" Or testCell = "FVB1" Or testCell = "FVB1E" Or testCell = "FVB4" Or testCell = "FVB4E" Then
```

---

```
For i = 13 To 501
    UB = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 364).End(xlUp).Row 'i - 10 controls column in Admin start at col 1.
    sh1.Cells(i, j).Value = sh2.Cells(Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB), i + 364)
Next
```

Within this loop, it appears that each iteration is finding the bottom row number with `UB = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 364).End(xlUp).Row`, could this be done before the loop?